# Shifting data with gnuplot candlesticks

Tags: ubuntu, plot, gnuplot

Several data files look like

```
1 342 345 564 
2 254 543 432
3 341 988 343
4 454 324 342
...
```

all with identical first column. I intend to use gnuplot candlesticks to plot the data. This is the function I'm using:

```
plot 'file1.txt' using 1:3:2:6:5:xticlabels(7) with candlesticks title '1' whiskerbars,
'file2.txt' using 1:3:2:6:5:xticlabels(7) with candlesticks title '2' whiskerbars lt 1 linecolor 3, 
'file3.txt' using 1:3:2:6:5:xticlabels(7) with candlesticks title '3' whiskerbars lt 1 linecolor 7
```

However, the lines are overlapping, and I would like the file1.txt data to start at, eg. 10, file2.txt data to start at 12, and file3.txt data to start at 14. The increments should be 10 for each. This way, I expect to get the row groupings of different files, with the separation in between.

How could this be achieved? Either a gnuplot adaptation, or the input file adaptation are acceptable (the latter implying that I first automatically change the first column for one file to multiple of 10, of another to multiple of 10 plus 2...)

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you want.  First, your datafile only has 4 columns, yet you reference up to y in your using spec.  Second "the increments should be 10 for each" but you say file1 starts at 10, file2 at 12 ...?  Finally, is that on the x-axis or the y-axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manipulate the first column, you can do so very easily using `using`.
e.g.:

```
 plot 'datafile' using 1:2, \
      'datafile' using (10*$1):2, \
      'datafile' using ((10+2)*$1):2

...
```

The first plot will have x-values equal to the first column, the second plot will have x values equal to `10*first_column`, the third plot will have x-values equal to `12*first_column`...

Comment: Thanks. What I actually needed was    ($1+2):3:2:6:5:xticlabels(7)

Comment: @user506901 -- Glad to help.  Gnuplot can do some pretty nifty things when you get to know it.